# UITableViewCell: Efficiency of drawing a background using CGContextRef versus a stretchable image

Tags: iphone, uitableview, cgcontext

I was looking up methods of altering the background view of a table view cell.

My initial reaction was to create an image with rounded corners, create a stretchable image from it, and set this as the cells background view when I create the cell. This seems to work pretty well in my experiments.

I also found this:
[How to customize the background/border colors of a grouped table view cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400965/how-to-customize-the-background-border-colors-of-a-grouped-table-view)
This work pretty well too.

Are there performance advantages to one method over the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a stretchable image will allow the OS to optimize by stretching the image using the graphics chip*. Drawing it in code will stretch it in the CPU. The former is more efficient.

* This depends on how the image is used, and is an implementation detail. The key word here is "allows".

Comment: Can you give an example of when the GPU may not kick in? Or how to ensure that it will be used?

Comment: If you draw the image using any of the methods on UIImage, it won't leverage the GPU. But if you assign it as the image for a UIImageView, then it is likely that it will.

Comment: Thanks. I also found this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838725/what-is-the-difference-between-uiimageview-and-drawinrect